# Event Hub - retry policy to continue retry forever

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventhub, retrypolicy

As per my business case, the processor application which processing the EventHub encounters any transient faults(429,449,503 etc) it should be retried as many times as it takes to succeed with exponential back-off in order to avoid data loss.

Does the EventHub lease will expire as the processor thread may go for longer sleep during retry's waiting period in exponential back-off approach?

Is above approach is recommended? if not how the data loss can be avoided during 429s or other transients faults?

Note: throwing message back to the Eventhub after few retries, is not an option in my case as it hampers the message ordering.

Comment: Without knowing the package and version that you're using, it's difficult to answer this.   It would also be helpful to see an example of the code that would potentially fail.

Comment: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs4.2.0 & polly7.2.1 are the packages used. Moreover Im asking about the recommended approach to do infinite retry while processing messages from Azure EventHub by keeping the lease alive during the infinite retry

Comment: Please provide a code sample of the Function body.